# How to display text in hover over in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I am very new to AngularJS. I want to display `{{Project.inrtcvalue}}` when the mouse is hovered over values. How can I do this in AngularJS?

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table" >
    <tr  ng-class="{'danger': project.rag <= 35, 'warning': project.rag > 35 && project.rag < 70  , 'success': project.rag > 70}" ng-repeat="project in $data">
        <td data-title="'PRN'" sortable="'prn'" filter="{'prn': 'text'}">
            {{project.prn}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So when the user hovers over these `<td>` I want to display a value from a controller. How do I do this? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You want to show it where?

Comment: Just like how you would hover over a box(<td>) and I want a little bubble showing a value when a user hover over the <td>

Comment: Dylan Watson gave you the simplest and the most efficient answer how to do this.

Comment: There is a problem with that, It is not printing the value, it is just print the expression as it is : {{project.inrtcvalue}}

Answer (score 15):

You should simply be able to use the `{{variable}}` notation within a HTML title tag.

So something like:

```
<td title="{{project.inrtcvalue}}">
```

See this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RQOTmteiJ86ZjENEzE1p?p=info) for an example (Thanks [dfsq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/949476/dfsq))

Comment: The html 'title' attribute will show the text when you mouseover the element (In this case, the td element)

Comment: This is printing {{project.inrtcvalue}}, rather than the actual value

Comment: Interesting.. Is your ng-repeat displaying the values within your table correctly?

Comment: Here is a demo of it working (first column): http://plnkr.co/edit/RQOTmteiJ86ZjENEzE1p?p=info

Comment: @dfsq It shows `{{user.name}}`. I guess, something has changed since then. FTR `ng-attr-title` works.

Comment: @maaartinus Script path was broken. http://plnkr.co/edit/upuGp6IoSXqLdaAi3kX5?p=preview

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ng-mouseover` and `ng-show` directives to accomplish this.Following is the example. [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/eGohFqiGKmkonmLwT3g1?p=preview) .Hope it helps to get you started.

Comment: How would I show the bubble showing the text on hover if I follow that example?